# JavaScript Mobile vs. Desktop issue

Tags: javascript, mobile, desktop, mutation-observers

This might be a little too precise to my situation here and difficult to answer, but I will give it a go.

I am trying to insert an image for a select your own seat ticketing website using JavaScript.  This is just a first draft, and I will be more precise with all the different database seat numbers and corresponding image files later, but I just wanted to get the code up and running correctly first.

This works 100% perfectly on the desktop version of the site (multiple browsers tested).  On the mobile version of the site (multiple browsers tested), it ALMOST works, except that it always returns the image corresponding to the PREVIOUS seat selected.  That is, the first seat selected, gets me the "else" image (since there is no previous seat), while every successive seat selected gives me the one I had selected prior to that one.

Pretty sure the issue is either in the embedded multiple MutationObservers I have going or else in the setId addEventListener somewhere, but I am not finding it.  I tried logging the mutations, but they always looked identical between desktop and mobile to me.  Thanks for any assistance.

```js
/* Initial declarations */
var i;
var j;
var k;
var dataSeatId;
var selectedId;
var priceTypeHeading;
var imgSrc;

/* Function to set the current database seat_no below */
function setId(evt) {
  selectedId = evt.currentTarget.dataset.tnSeatId;
}

/* Function to insert the SYOS preview image */
function insertImage(imageId, elementToMoveDown) {
    
    /* Get the correct URL and data for the image file that goes with that specific seat_no */
    
    
    
    if (imageId < 7000) {
        imgSrc = "https://thecenterpresents.org/media/5944/venue-rental-pallatte-request-a-quote-150x150.jpg";
    } else {
        imgSrc = "https://thecenterpresents.org/media/2018/visit-directions.jpg";
    }
    /* Use the below as a template for what to do when you actually build out the function to grab the seat info
    function getSeatInfo() {
        let imgUrl = "https://thecenterpresents.org/media/2695/asherwood-estatehome-box.jpg", /* 453x 356 for desktop; something for mobile;
            imgAlt = "The view of the Palladium stage from the selected seat";
    
        return {imgUrl , imgAlt};
    }
    
    var a;
    a = getSeatInfo();
    
    console.log(a.imgUrl);
    console.log(a.imgAlt);
    */

    /* Create the new image element and assign it the proper values */
    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.src = imgSrc;
    newImg.alt = "The view of the Palladium stage from the selected seat";
    newImg.id = "syos-preview";

    /* Actually insert the new image */
    elementToMoveDown.parentNode.insertBefore(newImg, elementToMoveDown);
}

/* Function to remove the SYOS preview image */
function removeImage() {
  var previewImage = document.getElementById("syos-preview");
  previewImage.remove();
}

/* First mutation observer variables */
const syos = document.getElementsByClassName("tn-syos")[0];

const config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};

/* Callback function for the second/inner mutation observer */
const priceTypeCallback = mutations => {
    
    /* Set initial value for i */
    i = 0;

    /* Loop through the mutations */
    while (i < mutations.length) {

        /* Only worry about mutations that are related to the specific node tree */
        if (mutations[i].type === "attributes" && mutations[i].target.classList[0] === "tn-syos-price-type-selector") {
 
            /* Grab the pop up box to use */
            var a = document.getElementsByClassName("tn-syos-price-type-selector")[0];
 
            /* Check to verify that the box is indeed loaded on the screen with content and that it does not already have the image added in the case of multiple mutations */
            if (a.style.display === "" && !a.innerHTML.includes("img") && !a.innerHTML.includes("The view")) {
                
                /* Insert the image */
                priceTypeHeading = mutations[i].target.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[2];
                insertImage(selectedId, priceTypeHeading);
                
                /* Add an event handler to pay attention to when the window is being closed so that it can remove the image */
                var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("tn-modal__btn-close")[0];
                closeButton.addEventListener("click", removeImage, false);
                
                /* Once the image is added or removed based on the case required, there is no need to keep cycling */
                break;

            } else {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
};

/* Callback function for the first mutation observer */
const callback = mutations => {
    
    /* Set initial value for j */
    j = 0;

    /* Loop through the mutations */
    while (j < mutations.length) {

        /* Only worry about mutations that are related to the specific node tree */
        if (mutations[j].type === "childList" && mutations[j].target.classList[0] === "tn-syos-seat-container") {

            /* Grab the database seat numbers */
            var allUses = document.getElementsByTagName("use");

            /* Loop through the seat numbers and add an event listener to track which exact seats are chosen */
            for (k = 0; k < allUses.length; k+=1) {
                dataSeatId = allUses[k].dataset.tnSeatId;
                var el = document.getElementsByTagName("use")[k];
                el.addEventListener("click", setId, false);
            }

            /* Second/Inner mutation observer variables */
            var priceTypeSelector = document.getElementsByClassName("tn-syos-price-type-selector")[0];

            var priceTypeConfig = {
                attributes: true
            };

            /* Create and turn on the second/inner mutation observer */
            var observer = new MutationObserver(priceTypeCallback);

            observer.observe(priceTypeSelector, priceTypeConfig);

        }

        j += 1;
    }
};

/* Create and turn on the first mutation observer */
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(syos, config);
```

JAM 2.0/pcsjunior002

Answer (score 1):

FYI in case anyone comes across this later and is experiencing the same issue.  The result was that I pretty much just had to re-write this a different way.  What was happening is that, due to the propagation of the elements on the page on mobile vs. desktop, different elements were being created first.  Thus the functions and selections would run in different orders.

While the imageId that I needed first was populated just fine on the desktop, the setting of that value had not yet happened, thus it returned null.  The else clause in my imgSrc clause ensured that I got a preliminary image, and then it always fell one behind as it was referencing the previous image which was updated as it was closed.

Anyway, there it is.